# How panda data frame read an excel file and print the data only if there is a change in a particular cell data of the excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, if-statement, while-loop

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Live_Data.xlsm','Sheet1',skiprows = 5,  nrows= 21, usecols = 'B:V')
print(df)
```

This code read the excel file from the 'B' to to 'v' column and prints the output. I am trying to use a loop function to check the excel sheet in some time interval and print the output only if there is a change in value suppose in the 'v' columns data.

Comment: It’s difficult not having any details about your data and contents of the columns. Basically, if you want to check the latest value with the second latest regarding the timeline, e.g. you may want to sort the df according to the TimeStamp column in descending order. Then compare the value in column V from the first row with the value from the second row.

Comment: Might also helpful if you share the code you have got so far and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could check timestamp to know if there were any change but it wont tell you what change. The way I see it you need something to compare to so have always to files (an auxiliar one) and upload them and see if are differences

```
df.equals(df2) # if True then some rows have changed, use pandas to see each one.
```

if there are differences you backup the file to be the auxiliar file for the next time you want to compare,

Comment: The excel sheet has live streaming data so some values are changing continuously but I need to print the data only if there is a change in the values of V column data.

Comment: You can always keep df2 in memory first time you acess the data online and everytime you acess the data online again read it to df and compare if there are differences then do what you intented to do but in the end  update df2 with the new data.

Comment: can u elaborate with sample codes, I am not getting what you explained?

Comment: You should post your code that way it will be easier